# Two definitions of the set of integers modulo $n$

Tags: elementary-number-theory, modular-arithmetic, definition

In [this Wikipedia page](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Modular_arithmetic#Integers_modulo_n), it defines the set of integers modulo $n$ as:

> $\mathbb{Z}/n\mathbb{Z}=\{\overline{a_n}\ \mid\ a\in\mathbb{Z}\}$

However in this sample page from *[Elementary Number Theory: Primes, Congruences, and Secrets](https://link.springer.com/chapter/10.1007/978-0-387-85525-7_2?noAccess=true)*, it defines it as:

> $\mathbb{Z}/n\mathbb{Z}=\{0,1,...,n-1\}$

Why are there two different definitions for the set of integers modulo $n$?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There is only the definition as equivalence classes.  But equivalence classes are more abstract than numbers so people prefer to just think of numbers and "going back to zero once you reach $n$".  But if we had to be super pedantic, we'd have to replace the numbers by equivalence classes.

If you want to be precise: Recall the notion of "equivalence class".  For given $n\in \mathbb N$, define an equivalence class on $\mathbb Z$ by $x\sim y$ if and only if $x$ and $y$ differ by a multiple of $n$.  Then the equivalence classes are
\[ \overline 0=\{ ...-2n,-n,\textbf 0,n,2n,...\}  \]
\[ \overline 1=\{ ...1-2n,1-n,\textbf 1,1+n,1+2n,...\} \]
\[ \overline 2=\{ ...2-2n,2-n,\textbf 2,2+n,2+2n,...\} \]
...
\[ \overline {n-1}=\{ ...n-1-2n,n-1-n,\textbf {n-1},n-1+n,...\} \]
and this is all the classes because the next one (for example) will be the same as the first one.

So we should write the set of integers modulo $n$ as $\\{ \overline 0,\overline 1,...,\overline {n-1}\\} $ but we usually drop the bars and take it for understood that in reality they're classes.